# Access different react paths with root in ingress

Tags: reactjs, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have two react apps, one is for administrators and the other is for normal users. Both have root `/` access. To enable the admin to access their page while normal user their respective pages, I added a redirect route in react router of admin, it redirects from `admin` to `/`.
I then added the two backends in my ingress a follows:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
     paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            serviceName: user-service
            servicePort: 3000

      - path: /admin
        pathType: Exact
          backend:
            serviceName: admin-service
            servicePort: 4000
```

The thing is this, it does not load the admin page. I don't know why... Is there a way to load this different apps with same root paths? (both root paths is `/`)

Comment: Haven't used react before. But to clarify somethings. The redirect route that you added, Changes the route from the clients side right? If so, Then that won't work.

Comment: thats right, it redirects the client side.. but again that client side is theoretically my backend.

Comment: Can you provide some test examples of requests from both ingress backends? Also logs from `Ingress` and your `backend` requests.

Comment: Have you tried moving your /admin path higher in the config than the / path? I've never used nginx-ingress but I have used nginx as a reverse proxy many times and typically the routes in these config files are read top down. I would assume that it would look at the servicePort before routing BUT in case it doesn't I think you want your exact routes to process BEFORE your prefix routes.

Comment: Have you tried switching the order of the paths? The longest one should have priority thought. Have you just tried 1 path and sending / to the admin service? If it doesn't work I would check the service port.

Answer (score 0):

In your admin service please make sure that you are serving from the relative path (here /admin).

In CRA you can do it by configuring the homepage in package.json

```
 "homepage": "http://example.com/admin",
```

Refer: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths

Comment: Actually it is an onpremise deplyoment. I am using ip addresses, can that work?

Comment: I am not sure how your react application is setup, maybe try this https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-set-react-router-default-route-redirect-to-home

Comment: try doing with `https://example.com/admin` or `/admin`

Comment: This has the underlying assumption that the developer knows the ingress sleeve before building the project, which might not always be the case.
Another way is to embed a root-crawler in the index.html that is returned by the SPA. The crawler tries to fetch some well-known resource until a 2XX status is returned. I.e. a small loop that attempts to resolve current path to this application's root path. For example the SPA is acquired from /admin/foo/index.html, first GET /admin/foo/.well-known (returns 404), then GET /admin/.well-known (returns 200), i.e. the root path is /admin

Answer (score 0):

This this maybe you want - Nginx rewrite

nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target

This is the full doc.
[rewrite](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/)